# How do I ask my manager for a Intern to Full Time Employee Conversion?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, internship, people-management, fulltime

So, it's been 6 weeks since my internship started. It's gonna end in like 4 weeks. I have a mid internship review coming up which would be like a 1:1 with my manager. So I am planning to know his intentions of converting me to a FTE, but I don't know how should I ask him or in a way that I don't sound weird(idk what word to use). Also any tips for 1:1's, like what all should be asked and stuff?

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186131/how-do-i-ask-my-manager-for-a-intern-to-full-time-employee-conversion <-> 
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186690/how-do-i-ask-my-manager-if-i-will-be-converted-to-a-full-time-employee

Answer (score 8):

It is OK to ask your manager in a direct and professional manner because this is a valid and professional question.

For example, you can talk to him and ask him as follows:

> **I really enjoy working here. It has been a great experience. I've learnt a lot, and always get along well with everyone. I will be very happy to finish the remainder of this wonderful internship with your team. By the way, after this internship, I will be looking for a full time job. Do you have any opening for a full time position? If yes, can I apply for it? Do you think I have a good chance of getting this full time position?**

Answer (score 1):

**Ask directly**

> I'm having a really good time here and I think I'm doing well. I'd be very interested in a full-time role. What do you think ?

A few things to consider

1. It's best to have the performance review first and get the feedback. If your boss tells you that you are doing great, they can't easily backpedal later
2. However, keep an eye on the clock. Make sure there is enough time left after the review to dive into the full-time question.
3. If the feedback you are getting is mostly negative, than this will be unlikely to fly. Still there is no harm in asking, but you can play it by ear.
4. An evasive answer counts as a "no". You are already 6 weeks in with only 4 weeks left. If they are planning on keeping you, they already know by now or are very close to make the call. Start polishing your resume and applying elsewhere.