# How do I ask my manager if I will be converted to a full time employee?

Tags: software-industry, communication, career-development, internship

I'm currently doing an internship, which has a week left to run. A few weeks back I asked my manager regarding my performance and all but he said the general stuff like "enthusiasm is great" and "you are focused". My mentor says a similar thing

I am anxious about whether or not I will get an offer to return as a full time employee or not. Should I ask my manager directly about it, or should I do something else?

**Edit**:  FYI, I will graduate in 8 months. I will go back to school for my final 2 semesters.

Comment: @LoremIpsum edited .

Comment: Asking about FTE / Full-Time Employee (though FTE actually stands for Full-time Equivalent, i.e. 1 person working full time is 1 FTE, 2 people working 50% is also 1 FTE) is not your real question. Your question is if they will offer you a job after your internship.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ask my manager for a Intern to Full Time Employee Conversion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186131/how-do-i-ask-my-manager-for-a-intern-to-full-time-employee-conversion) - or specifically, did you follow any of the suggestions there, and if so what happened?

Comment: If (1) there is a possibility in general for internships to turn into permanent appointments,   and (2) they want you for one, you'll hear about it.

Comment: Will you graduate right after this internship ? Or will you go back to school for a few semesters and will graduate after that ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I will go back to school for my final 2 semesters . I will graduate in 8 months.

Comment: Take it easy. Think about graduating and then think of applying to jobs that make you feel good and confident about yourself. Why would anyone choose to work in an environment that makes them highly  [stressed and anxious](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186237/its-been-hell-everyday-i-am-stressed-and-anxious-feel-like-crying)?

Answer (score 11):

I think it's an absolute mistake to assume that if your performance is good, you will be offered a FTE role.

Many organisations offer internships that do not represent a pathway into FTE.

If you need to know if they are going to make an offer to you, you need to ask them explicitly.

But regardless of their answer, until you have a signed contract in front of you, you should be spending time getting your resume up to scratch, and sending out applications to other organisations.

Comment: That’s what I am asking , like how do i ask them explicitly?

Comment: @RCoder "Hey boss, will I be getting a full time offer at the end of this internship?"

Answer (score 0):

You have commented that you will graduate after 8 more months (2 more semesters). You will not graduate right after the end of this internship in about 1 week.

Therefore, it is reasonable that the manager won't be able to convert you to a full time employee right now. Normally, a manager will only convert an intern into a full time employee after that intern graduates (and if that intern has all the qualified skills and experiences for the job.)

You can ask your manager now, but he won't be able to give you a concrete and meaningful answer.

**Realistically, he can't really promise to hire you or anyone else as a full time employee 8 months from now. No one knows for sure if, 8 months from now, that company will hire more workers or layoff more workers.**

So, I would suggest that you maintain a good working relationship with the manager for now. You could apply for another internship in 1 semester. Or, you could stay in school for the last 2 semesters to complete your degree and then apply for a full time position with that company.

Comment: by getting converted to a full time employee i mean getting a return offer basically .

Comment: @RCoder - They cannot predict what will happen in 8 months

Comment: It depends on the company. I interned at a company where it was very normal to extend full time offers even if the intern still had a year of school left. The offer was contingent, of course, on you finishing your degree in a satisfactory manner.

Answer (score 0):

As an advice from my own experience *(Im currently doing my internship and i will graduate this december)*, i asked directly to my manager if i could get a full time job when my internship ends, explaining him which things i liked from working there, things that i learned, and fortunately i got a quick answer

In short words, you should do the same, ask him directly and try to get a concise answer, at this point you should know how you sold yourself to the company and if they saw value on your work already.